# Laravel. Route passing incorrrect parameter to destroy() in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am using Laravel 5.6.26. When I try to delete a paricular post by sending id to destroy(), it show correct id on blade. But when I dd($id) at PostsController, it show different id. Why? Can anyone explain it to me? Thank you!

**home.blade.php**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

  <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#b3e0ff">

    <div class="btn-group float-right">
      <span  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
         </span>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="{{$post->id}}">
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li>


            <a href="#" onclick=" 
                var result = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this {{$post->id}}?');
                    if( result ){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();

                    } "> Delete
            </a>

            <form id="delete-form" action="{{ route('posts.destroy',['$id'=> $post->id]) }}"  method="POST" style="display: none;">

                      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}

                       {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            </form>


          </li>

          </ul>
    </div>@endforeach {{ $posts->links() }}
```

**alert on blade**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK4Uo.jpg

**PostsController.php**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //

    dd($id);

}
```

**dd**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSMl7.jpg

But When I try modify the route parameter to this

```
route('posts.destroy',['$id'=> 5]) }}
```

I get the correct dd 5 at PostsController.

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

Comment: posts.destroy is a route name? show route file

Comment: post.destroy not a name route

Comment: {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}

Comment: How the source looks?

Comment: action="{{ route('posts.destroy',['$id'=> $post->id]) }}"  not will work instead of route('posts.destroy',['$id'=> $post->id]) use url('posts.destroy',['$id'=> $post->id])

Comment: Because I am using pagination, I noticed that if that particular page has 5 posts,when I delete each of them, it just dd the first post's id, instead of their own id.

Comment: It's not first post ID but rather number of rows affected. When you delete the row, return is `(int)1` since one row is affected by that action or number of rows have being deleted if you were passing array of integers. [Docs](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L798).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I did't get the correct id, just need to modify this

```
delete-form
```

to this

```
delete-form_{{$post->id}}
```